# CSS3 File Tab with Inset Corners on the Bottom

Tags: css

[image: rounded corner image]

Hi,

Can anyone help me to create below mentioned design in css3. I've tried the following property, but still having the problem to get the exact design

```
background:#c6d92d;
height: 5em;
width: 20em;
-moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
border-radius: 5em 5em 1em 1em;
padding:20px;
```

Thanks

Comment: The way you have that inset curve on the bottom leads me to believe you'll need more than one element to reproduce this.

Comment: @MetalFrog : how would you name this shape ? A new title for this question would be useful.

Comment: It's kinda like a file tab, so maybe something along the lines of "CSS3 File Tab with Inset Corners on the Bottom" would help? Trapezoid with flared edges? I'm sure there's a term for that specific curve type, but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

You need more than one div to achieve that.

You must put two other divs (one at left and one at right) white with radius over a black background.

This is an effect I achieved in my site : http://dystroy.org/re7210/ (click "Toutes les recettes").

You do it like this :

```
        _________
       /         \
div C |  div A    |  div B
     /            \
```

C and B are white div covering 100% of cells having a black background (which is visible only where the border-radius isn't 0).

In this case, the div at the right of the main one has this css :

```
#divB {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Here's my final effect :

[image]

And here's my "divB", which should make evident where I have white over black and where I have black over white :

[image]

(As you can see, I found easier to compose all this using a table but you probably can do it without table)

Comment: No actually this can be one using one single div element using CSS3 and I'm using a library which can make support for IE browsers as well.

Comment: @Mujahid To be fair, if you were able to do this with one element, and you knew you could do it, you wouldn't have a question open on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dystroy: this seems ok, but I hope we can do as it in the following link [link](http://css3shapes.com/) and see #trapezium in that page, that thing is ok, but I have make the rounded borders to it...

Comment: I don't think you can have your bottom inset round corners this way.

Comment: @Mujahid As I suspected, your single element example is nowhere near what your image depicts. :P

Answer (score 1):

The properties you are looking for are:
`border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius`
http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: but when I set `border-radius:5em 5em 1em 1em`, this will set top-left and top-right radius 5em right? anyway I'll try

Comment: he already uses border-radius which to set the top left and top right radius

Comment: Yes, I read this too fast. I also didn't notice he has the corners rounded the opposite way at the bottom.